# Torque From An Area of Impact

Tags: torque

I understand that torque is defined as the cross product of the difference vector between the point of impact and the center of mass and the force vector, but what happens when the impact is over an area? Do I just find the center of the area and use that as the impact point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the *weighted* center of the impact: when you have many forces acting on a rigid object, you can always find a single force vector (the vector sum of all the other vectors) that gives rise to the same motion.

In the case of an impact over an area, you will want to determine the force at each point, and take the vector sum. If the object impacting is symmetrical, that point will be at the center; if it's not - then you will have a possibly hard integral ahead of you...